# Vs Code Live SASS Compiler Taking Long time to load

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, live-sass-compiler

I've been using the Live SASS Compiler for VS Code for awhile now and have never had this issue. It was working fine yesterday.
When I save a file, Live SASS starts compiling the saved styles and just shows "Working on it" on the bottom status bar. I do not get any errors in my terminal. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the extension and have had no luck.
Any advise would be greatly appreciated.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epFCj.png)

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-sass-compiler/issues/352 Also think about switching to Dart SASS as Live SASS support has stopped, per the last comment on the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. Turn out, it was just a simple syntax error of the sass file. such as forgetting ";" in somewhere. My visual studio code didn't detect the syntax error so you may have to look it up by yourself.